# Index reorganize is causing the table's indexes to disable their page level locking?

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a strange experience when in a previously successful stored procedure, it did the following:-

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON Prices_Staging REBUILD;  
TRUNCATE TABLE Prices_Empty;  
ALTER TABLE Prices switch TO Prices_Empty;  
ALTER TABLE Prices_Staging switch TO Prices;
```

This always worked in the past, however frequently, the 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.Prices_Staging REBUILD;' statement is timely and fragmentation is only 0.3% !

I introduced a test into the sp to check average fragmentation for the table's indexes...

```
SET @Frag = (SELECT 
sum(avg_fragmentation_in_percent)
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
    (
DB_ID(@DATABASE)
,OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
,OBJECT_ID(@IndexName)
,NULL
,NULL
))

If @Frag > 30
BEGIN

ALTER INDEX ALL ON Prices_Staging REBUILD;     

END
ELSE
BEGIN

ALTER INDEX ALL ON Prices_Staging SET(ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON);       
ALTER INDEX ALL ON Prices_Staging REORGANIZE;

END

Now, the final SWITCH fails as it reports that the indexes are not the same between staging and prices ?
```

Further investigation reveals that all the indexes on the table have had their Page Level Locking disabled.

I can remedy the problem by rebuilding all the indexes on the table.

So what is causing the REORGANIZE to disable the Page Level Locking ?